# What is the difference between 'way' and 'path' in Proverbs 3:6?

Tags: proverbs

**Proverbs 3:6 (NASB)**

> In all your ways acknowledge Him,
>
> And He will make your paths straight.

What is the difference between a "way" and a "path"?

More specifically, what is the significance in using two different words for what seems to be the same thing?

Comment: Welcome to BH Stack Exchange, @sara. Interesting question - I noticed that Job 6:18 also uses both Hebrew words, straight after each other.

Comment: Hebrew poetry often uses synonyms to purposely mean the same thing.

Comment: Hi Sara, welcome to Hermeneutics! I made an edit to adjust your format. I hope this proves helpful. And, great question!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, sara, the two different words are not directing to the same thing. The English versions are very accurate here. See below two examples:

> **Proverbs 3:6**

- > In all your ways acknowledge him, and he shall direct your paths
  >   (**AKJV**).
- > In all your ways acknowledge Him, And He will make your paths smooth
  >   (**TNK**)

In the LXX they used the same word for both:

> **Proverbs 3:6**
>
> ἐν πάσαις ***ὁδοῖς*** σου γνώριζε αὐτήν ἵνα ὀρθοτομῇ τὰς ***ὁδούς***
>   σου ὁ δὲ πούς σου οὐ μὴ προσκόπτῃ

Yet in the Hebrew there are two different words with quite a different meaning:

> **Proverbs 3:6**
>    בְּכָל־דְּרָכֶ֥יךָ דָעֵ֑הוּ וְ֝ה֗וּא יְיַשֵּׁ֥ר אֹֽרְחֹתֶֽיךָ׃

1. דְּרָכֶ֥יךָ < 
   דֶּרֶךְ (n-m) heb
   way, road, distance, journey, manner
   road, way, path
   journey
   direction
   manner, habit, way
   of course of life (fig.)
   of moral character (fig.)
2. אֹֽרְחֹתֶֽיךָ <
   אֹרַח (n-m) heb
   way, path
   path, road
   the path, way, passing of life (fig.)
   way of living (fig.)
   traveller, wayfarer (meton)

For more, please have a look [here](https://netbible.org/bible/Proverbs+3) and [here](https://parabible.com/Proverbs/3).

So, the expression "all your ways" is about the whole area of one's beliefs, way of thinking, life's actions, etc. And it is not simply in theory, but also in practice, in everyday's routine. Whereas "paths" is about the work of God in most likely every event of one's life, at a more down to earth level, where God will be removing all obstacles out of the way.

In a more abstract way of putting it, "all your ways" is about the general and "paths" is about the particular. If you travel say, "from Chicago to LA" :-) there is one way (direction), but many paths (means of getting to the destination).

That would be: "*if on the whole you acknowledge him, he shall be looking after you in every detail of your life*."

Answer (score 0):

Although ארח and דרך are both "way" , or "path" the first is more figurative and related to the way one should act (metaphorical way / path of life).

This verse say that one should remember God commandments on every step he make: the path he walks in and the way he acts.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly...you've answered it very well

The Way is the Purpose, Vision, Direction, general

The Path is the Plans, the specifics, the steps to be taken to get to the vision.

Simply, the Way is made up of paths.

Comment: You seem to be commenting on an answer, not answering the question. Please leave this area clear for answers. Please see the Tour and the help (below, bottom left) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Welcome to BH.

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE. Please take the [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand what we do here.

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that “way” can describe more than one connected road or path. But we use “path” to describe just one singular road or route. An example of this is: Can you tell me the way to the beach?

The direction of your life follows the commitments you make.
The practical meaning of proverbs 3:6 means
In all your commitments (ways) acknowledge God and He will
Make  your decisions (path) straight